# Android emulator doesn't start

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

My Android Launch, the adb start but stay at "Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...". But doesn't install the App. If I go in Run As Android App, if I do that, the App is installed with sucess and the Activity is started, but at the device screen doesn't show anything, the name Android stay at the screen for ever. And the LogCat doesn't show any error. Sorry, but English is not my first language. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Genymotion. You can download a version for Windows/Mac OS X/Linux after registering. A plugin for Eclipse is also avaliable.

i give you link [Genymotion Emulator](http://www.genymotion.com/) please download and setup.

as per my experience Genymotion Vertual device is faster then android emulator.

Comment: it is worth noting that genymotion is only free for non-commercial use. the business version comes in at about 400 dollars.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the ARM based emulator - it's very (VERY!) slow.

Two options I would recommend:

1. Make sure you're using [HAXM (VM Acceleration)](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#acceleration)
2. Try using [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/)

Comment: I waited more then 10min and nothing. I just installed the Eclipse for Android. It's a new computer that I'm working.

Comment: Same here; I'm running on several machines, including a quadcore 4x3.6 GHz with 32 GB RAM, and on all of them I gave up after 15+ minutes of boot animation. Is this really how slow the ARM emulator is supposed to be? The Android logo is animated very fluently, it just never goes away.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have more than 4GB RAM and a i5 (or comparable) processor then the emulator ends up taking a lot of time. Try to close all other applications except eclipse and the emulator and let the emulator be the only application focused in your desktop. Else try to run it on a lower avd e.g. 2.3.3